# Running docker from a non root cloud builder

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, bazel, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to run docker in a cloud build step with a non-root cloud builder container. It's running a Bazel test that requires that the user is not root.

I tried adding the user to the docker, root, or google-sudoers group in the container but, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share the error that you are getting while running the container?

Answer (score 1):

By default, both the applications running within Docker containers and the containers themselves have root privileges.There are two methods to run docker as follows

- Method 1 – Add user to Docker group
- Method 2 – Using Docker file
  Kindly refer to this [document](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/run-docker-as-a-non-root-user/) for more information. Thank you!